# Add function reference to list

Tags: c++, list, function

My question is rather simple, however i was unable to find anything about it on google (possibly because i am new to c++ and don't quite know the right terminology for everything yet). My question is, is it possible for me to add a reference to a function in a list, and if so, what is the correct way to do it?

Basically what i'm trying to do is to create an event class that would be able to store function references in a list so that i could do some basic event handling.

What im thinking of doing is something like this:

```
list<function> fnlist;
void add(function fn) {
    fnlist.add(fn);
}
void call() {
    for (function &fn: fnlist) {
        fn();
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible?
Please note that i would like to avoid using any event libraries if i could do this without any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following :

```
/* ret_type : Return Type, 
   arg_type - type of argument (can be multiple, separated by comma)
*/

typedef std::function<ret_type( arg_type )> function ;

std::list < function> fnlist ;


void add(function fn) 
{
    fnlist.add(fn);
}

void call()
{
    for (const auto &fn: fnlist) 
    {
       fn();
    }
}
```

Comment: Allright, thanks. This seems relatively easy to implement. But what if i were to call a function that would accept arguments? Would i just change `void(void)` to `void(type)`? EDIT: Thanks. I posted the question before the update. This looks understandable.

Comment: typedef std::function<float (int x, int y)> function ; you can.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, this is possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void quick() {
    cout << "quick ";
}
void brown() {
    cout << "brown ";
}
void fox() {
    cout << "fox ";
}

int main() {
    vector<function<void()> > events;
    events.push_back(quick);
    events.push_back(brown);
    events.push_back(fox);
    for (auto f : events) {
        f();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Use `std::function<void()>` to hold a functional object that encapsulates a callable that takes no parameters, and does not return a result.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/590X4O).